# How to Get createAsyncThunk In The Correct Way Data React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am a new in react native Redux Newest Documentation. I want to use **createAsyncThunk**
to get my api data using Axios.

Below my code :

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ApiChartingSlice from './redux/slice/api/ApiChartingSlice';
import LoginNavigator from './navigation/LoginNavigator';



const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {    
    ApiChartingMenu: ApiChartingSlice
  }
});


export default function App() {
  return (        
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );

}
```

**ApiChartingAxios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { BasicAuthUsername, BasicAuthPassword } from "../utility/utility";
    
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://blablabla.id/index.php',
    headers: {
        auth: {
            username: BasicAuthUsername,
            password: BasicAuthPassword
          }
    }
});
```

**SubApiChartingAxios.js**

```
import ApiChartingAxios from "../ApiChartingAxios";
    
export const SubApiChartingMenu = async () => {
    const response = await ApiChartingAxios.get('/ApiChartingMenu',{
        params: null
    });          
            
    return response;
};
```

**ApiChartingSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { SubApiChartingMenu } from '../../../api/subapi/SubApiChartingAxios';


export const ApiChartingMenuThunk = createAsyncThunk(
    'ApiChartingMenu',
    async () => {
        const response = await SubApiChartingMenu();
        console.log(response);
        return response.data.Data;        
    } 
)
  
  
// status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
const ApiChartingMenuSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'ApiChartingMenu',
    initialState: {
        apiData: {},
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [ApiChartingMenuThunk.pending.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: "loading",
                apiData: {},
                error: {},
            };
        },
        [ApiChartingMenuThunk.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: "idle",
                apiData: action.payload,
                error: {},
            };
        },
        [ApiChartingMenuThunk.rejected.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: "idle",
                apiData: {},
                error: action.payload,
            };
        },
    }
});


export default ApiChartingMenuSlice.reducer;
```

And the last is my screen output:

**ChartScreen.js**

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ApiChartingMenuSlice, ApiChartingMenuThunk } from '../../redux/slice/api/ApiChartingSlice';


const ChartScreen = () => { 
    console.log('ChartScreen');    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(dispatch(ApiChartingMenuThunk()));    
    
    const chartData = useSelector(state => state.ApiChartingMenu.apiData);    
    console.log(chartData);
    

    return (        
        <View>
            <Button title="test" onPress={() => {}} />
        <ChartComponent />
        </View>
    );
};


export default ChartScreen;
```

Problem:
I don't know why in my **ChartScreen.js** this line : `console.log(dispatch(ApiChartingMenuThunk()));`

return :

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
  "abort": [Function abort],
  "arg": undefined,
  "requestId": "oqhkA7eyL_VV_ea4FDxr3",
  "unwrap": [Function unwrap],
}
```

But in **ApiChartingSlice.js** in this line **console.log(response);**

return the correct value.

So, what is the correct way to retrive the value from the **createAsyncThunk** from my **ChartScreen.js**

The Api content is a list menu.

I want when first open the apps It execute the redux and show all my list menu.

But now just try to console.log the **ApiChartingMenuThunk** in **ApiChartingSlice.js** is not working.

Can anybody solve and guide me to a solution ? Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself the problem is on this file :
**ApiChartingSlice.js**

and this line should be :

```
[ApiChartingMenuThunk.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
            state.playerList = {
                status: "idle",                
                apiData: state.apiData.push(action.payload),
                error: {},
            };
```

also you need to dispatch using this code :

in file **ChartScreen.js**

this is how we dispatch it.

```
const toggleGetMenuHandler = useCallback(() => {        
        dispatch(ApiChartingMenuThunk())
        .unwrap()
        .then((originalPromiseResult) => {        
            // console.log(originalPromiseResult);        
        })
        .catch((rejectedValueOrSerializedError) => {        
            console.log(rejectedValueOrSerializedError);        
        })
    }, [dispatch]);    


    useEffect(() => {
      toggleGetMenuHandler();                
    }, [toggleGetMenuHandler]);
        },
```

Now this code : `const chartData = useSelector(state => state.ApiChartingMenu.apiData);`
will have a correct data.